# Usage of the adverbial "как будто"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Вам не кажется, что эту яму **как`-`будто** специально кто-то вырыл?

I assume this "[как будто](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%BE#Russian)" is an adverbial phrase, not a conjunction, given its position. When you use "как будто" as an adverbial phrase, does it serve to qualify an immediately following word -- in this case, "специально"?

And how does it differ in meaning from using "будто" as a conjunction:

> vs: Вам не кажется, `что` **будто**<sup>**`3`**</sup> специально<sup>**`4`**</sup> эту<sup>**`1`**</sup> яму<sup>**`2`**</sup> кто-то вырыл?

Comment: yes it does, the difference between будто and как-будто, if any, must be very subtle, difficult to pinpoint

Answer (score 2):

I am Russian but not linguist. I am going to tell how I understand this but I do not know any language theory behind this.

In your example you can use `будто` and `как будто` interchangeably. I think nowadays they more likely say `как будто` in this case.

Yes the word `как будто` is used to qualify an immediately following word or even a sentence.

If they say `эту яму специально кто-то вырыл` this might sound like accusation which in this case is obviously wrong. If they add `как будто` they soften the accusation and say that this seems like it was done intentionally but we know that it was not.

Let's look at couple examples.

I say to my friend:

```
Ты как будто хочешь меня обидеть.
```

This means that I expect and hope that they have no intention to offend me but they behave like they do, they make me feel they are offending me. The translation might be:

```
You seem to want to offend me.
```

Another example:

```
Как будто мне заняться нечем!
```

It might be translated:

```
As if I have nothing to do!
```

In this example `Как будто` effects the meaning of the next sentence `мне заняться нечем`. It changes the meaning to the contrary, as if I say that I have a lot to do now, but also adds some emotions and irony to the statement.

I think I can remember the time when the expression `как будто` become popular as a filter word. People tend to use to fill in the pause or to sound modern and cool.

I think the old school version for the last example might be

```
Мне больше заняться нечем!
```

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо за замечание! Исправил.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't emphasise anything here. This can be translated as 'as if' in both cases. Maybe you have a different example ?...

Comment: Sorry, wrong wording! What was I thinking? I meant "qualify".

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, I understand you correctly. But you can remove `будто` in both cases and their meanings will not change and the new phrases will be acceptable. (Of course, the phases will lose 'as if' meaning)

Comment: sr9yar makes a good point, either part of как-будто can be used alone, как is colloquial